# Extracting walkable coordinates from 3d scene

Tags: 3d, mmo, godot

is there away to extract the walkable coordinates from 3d scene , so I can have server side validation ? or how would I achieve that with Godot?

EDIt (clarification):

I was just wondering how they are validating the movement from the server side , let's say Fortnite,pubg or any MMORPG game , how they make sure that the player move from this position to this position? , what came in my mind was , if I can get the walkable points/coordinates save them to file , and on the server side , when a player wants to move from this point to this point , I check my map file , if this point is walkable then allow it , idk if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract (…) coords", but what comes to mind is to query a `Navigation` node, in particular for walkable space. You should be able to find tutorials of how to use it with a simple web search. I'm not sure if that's the best for your case. Perhaps `test_move` or `Raycast` plus checking velocity would suffice, assuming you are checking frequently enough and you want to consider jumping over gaps (which aren't walkable, but jumpable).

Comment: @Theraot I was just wondering how they are validating the movement from the server side , let's say Fortnite,pubg or any MMORPG game , how they make sure that the player move from this position to this position? , what came in my mind was , if I can get the walkable points/coordinates save them to file , and on the server side , when a player wants to move from this point to this point , I check my map file , if this point is walkable then allow it , idk if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: One way to do it is to send the input to the server, then the server can perform the actions. I cannot tell for certain which games do that. Having just the points won't do, you need areas. See [navigation mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh), used for bots, for example. Let us say the player moved from one side of a wall to the other, there is a path that goes around, are you checking infrequently enough that the player had time to walk that? If you check frequently enough, you might instead check if the player didn't exceed its velocity, and didn't go through obstacles.

Comment: I think that could be an Answer, @Theraot.